# How can I force seaborn or matplotlib to always render isolated values in heatmaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, renderer

I am analyzing long series of events using heatmaps. Values of the column are most of the time 0 but occasionally are 1 unfortunately the rendering behaviour often hide the 1 occurrences because of the 0 surrounding them. I have tried to use `antialiased=False` but it did not solve the problem:

This code reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2000, 4)))
for i in range(4):
    for j in [34,223,56,666]:
        d[i][j] = 1
axS = sns.heatmap(d,antialiased=False)
```

[image]

There should be 4 lines instead only one is visible. Of course, if I stretch the plot I have better results but still some values are hidden.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,30)
axB = sns.heatmap(d,antialiased=False)
```

I would like to force the rendering of isolated values. Is there any way to get this behaviour?

P.S. I need heatmaps because I compare multiple variables with float values, so `spy` for instance is not a good option for me.

Comment: This comment?: "P.S. I need heatmaps because I compare multiple variables." does not make very much sense to me as, of course, many other styles of plot permit the comparison of multiple variables.

Comment: @mwaskom  you are right sorry i rephresed it

Answer (score 1):

If these events are infrequent, you could reduce the resolution of the vertical axis by aggregating the values into bins.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2000, 4)))
for i in range(4):
    for j in [34,223,56,666]:
        d[i][j] = 1

x1 = d.index.min() - 1e-9
x2 = d.index.max()
bin_width = 50
bin_edge = np.arange(x1, x2 + bin_width, bin_width)
bin_center = np.arange(x1 + bin_width/2, x2, bin_width)
index_binned = pd.cut(d.index, bins=bin_edge, labels=bin_center)
d = d.join(pd.Series(index_binned, name="index_binned"))
d_binned = d.groupby('index_binned').sum()
sns.heatmap(data=d_binned, antialiased=False)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: interesting approach thanks but it is a little bit invasive

Comment: heatmap might not be the best visualization option for sharp and sparse data. A better approach would be using dots or lines.